# First character lost when writing data to file

Tags: c++

I'm facing a problem regarding data entry in file. I'm making arrays which terminate when I press enter key but the problem is that the character at 0 index is not in file while the rest of the indexes are there. In other words,while writing to the file my first character of the array got missed and was not present in the file.

My code is as follows:

```
char CNIC[10000];
std::fstream file1;

cout<<"Enter CNIC's >>>>>>>>>>> "<<endl;
file1.open("Nadra database.txt",std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
if(!file1)
{
    cout<<"File was not open";
}
else
{
    for(int i=0;i<11;i++)
    {
       char ch = getche();
       if((int)ch==13)
       {
             cout<<"Press Enter key to close data entry "<<endl;
             break;
       }
       else
       {
           for(int i=0;i<11;i++)
           {
                char character = getche();
                if((int)character==13)
                {
                       break;
                }
                else
                {
                     CNIC[i]=character;
                     file1<<CNIC[i];
                } 
           }
           file1<<endl;
      }
 } 

}
system("pause");
```

Comment: Rather than comparing characters to numbers, compare them to character literals.  For example, `if (character == '\r')`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why your outer loop even exists.  Can you explain a little clearer what this code is supposed to be doing?

Comment: Why are you using `getche` instead of `cin`?

Answer (score 2):

You aren't doing anything with ch in the beginning of your first else clause.  You need to write it to the file like you do in your inner loop.  Also, you need to change your inner loop to use j instead of i... never use the same temporary for nested loops.